# How to Pass Element As Argument In Event Listener

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a program that has a large number of reusable elements that all need an event listener. Because of this, I need a way to get the element from the listener. Here is what I want to do in code:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class").forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function(element/*The element that the event listener is assigned to, passed as an argument*/) {
        console.log(element) //Print out the element that was clicked in the console
    })
})
```

Is there any way to replicate this or something of the sort in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the clicked element with the `this` keyword or your looping variable (`el`) inside the event callback. `this` is generally preferred because you won't have to worry about changing the code in the callback if your looping variable name changes and it avoids setting up a closure around `el`, which (under the right circumstances) could have unintended side-effects.

But, also be aware the `.querySelectorAll()` returns a "node list" and not an actual `Array` and `.forEach()` is an `Array` method. Some browsers don't support calling `.forEach()` on a node list, so you should convert that node list into a proper `Array` for best compatibility.

```js
// Get the matching nodes in a node list and convert to an Array
let ary = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".test"));

// Now, you can safely use .forEach()
ary.forEach(function(el) {
    // Callbacks are passed a reference to the event object that triggered the handler
    el.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        // The this keyword will refer to the element that was clicked
        console.log(this.id, el); 
    });
})
```

```html
<div class="test" id="div1">Click me</div>
<p class="test" id="p1">No, click me</p>
<div class="test" id="div2">What about me?</div>
<h1 class="test" id="h1">Now, click me</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, you can reference variables in outer blocks/functions without having to pass them into inner functions:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class").forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(element) {
    console.log(el);
  })
});
```

If the element that triggers the click is the `.class` itself (rather than one of `.class`'s descendants), you can also use `event.target` to identify it:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class").forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
  })
});
```

If you *have* to pass the element as a parameter to a function for some reason rather than accessing the element in the outer scope, I suppose you could use`bind`:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class").forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", logElement.bind(null, el));
});
function logElement(element) {
  console.log(element);
}
```